# OLEDB Connection from Excel to Oracle Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, excel, ado, vba

Everyone,

A VBA problem has been killing me the past two days. I have a Macro Based Model in Excel that has data sets bought into the spreadsheets from Oracle via OLEDB. To illustrate the problem simply I have created two functions within the Model.  One using ODBC("odbc") and another using OLEDB("OraOLEDB").  The code was working completely fine last week and it has not been changed.

Now, however I get an error message that states "Run-Time Error '424': Object Required when I execute the line "conn.Open strCon" in sub "OraOLEDB".A connection can't be established with the database!  So when I am trying to establish a connection to the database with that line of code, it fails.  What is interesting is that via ODBC, a connection can be established. The line "conn.Open strCon" in sub "odbc" executes successfully and I am able to establish a connection to the database.

I did not change anything in the Excel Model but I did have a bunch of windows updates recently.  I don't know if that corrupted anything.  I think it may have.  The reason why I don't want to use the ODBC connection is that it is significantly slower.  I get run times 10x faster using OLEDB.  Please let me know if you can help.

---

```
Sub odbc()
Dim conn As Object
Dim strCon As String

strCon = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; 
          CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) 
             (HOST=xxx)(PORT=1521))
             (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxx))); 
          uid=xxx;pwd=xxx;"

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

conn.Open strCon

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub OraOLEDB()
Dim conn As Object
Dim strCon As String

strCon = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;
          Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
             (HOST = xxx)(PORT = 1521)) 
             (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = xxx)));   
          User Id=xxx;Password=xxx"

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

conn.Open strCon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means  `Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")` returns nothing. Check ADODB.dll registration. Alternatively you may use

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
```

and you'll see if ADODB is available at the moment you edit the script not waiting for runtime errors.

Comment: Serg.  Defining the variables this way fixed it.  Thank you.

Comment: @jp3nyc: Please mark the answer that helped you best as accepted so that we the readers know exactly which answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I see the host for the OLEDB connection is modn-ast-**fdb1**. ...  while for the ODBC connection you have modn-ast-**tdb1**. ...   Shouldn't the host be the same?

Comment: Thanks mathguy.  Change made.